# Kann man "andere" anstatt eines "weitere" in diesem Kontext benutzen?

Tags: meaning

> Falls Sie **weitere** Informationen zu anderen Themen der Gitarre haben möchten wie Gitarre stimmen, Gitarre lernen, Gitarristen, verschiedene Gitarrentypen, Fachwörterverzeichnis, und vieles mehr, so können Sie diese auf den in dieser Aufzählung verlinkten Webseiten erhalten.

Warum verwendet man **weitere** anstatt eines **andere** in diesem Zusammenhang? Ändert es sich die Bedeutung des Satzes dadurch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Weitere Informationen* sind zusätzliche oder mehr Informationen. *Andere Informationen* sind *unterschiedliche oder andersartige Informationen*.
Man würde den Satz auch mit *andere* verstehen, aber die Bedeutung würde nicht so gut passen. Zudem wird im selben Satz bereits das Wort *"anderen"* benutzt. Deshalb wäre eine zweite Nutzung desselben Wortes zwar korrekt, aber "nicht schön".
Man könnte auch Folgendes sagen:

> Falls Sie andere Informationen zu Themen der Gitarre haben möchten …

Dennoch ist es üblicher *weitere* zu sagen.

Comment: Des Weiteren ist es zu erwähnen, dass mit dem Begriff "weitere" Information implementiert wird, dass es sich um ein Hinzufügen von Informationen handelt.